# Picking the right data structure

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, hashset

I'm trying to teach myself java. I'm trying to write a program that takes a string with no spaces and separates it into words.

My plan of attack was to partition the dictionary based on word length, then walk through the string finding possible variations.

I ran into a problem with making my dictionary. I've read up on the various collections, and I thought that an array (of length 20 or so) holding HashSets would work best for me, but I can't figure out how to declare it. I think an array would be good because the index would represent the length, then a HashSet would be good because I could store the words as keys for fast look ups.

This is something that I could do in seconds in the scripting languages I'm most comfortable with, but I've spent about 5 hours reading up and trying to figure it out in Java. Historically speaking, this is evidence that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. Can someone with more java acumen help get me going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only question is the syntax, then to create an array of 20 HashSets, the syntax would be:

```
HashSet[] mySets = new HashSet[20];
```

Comment: Eclipse throws this error when I try to use this: `Cannot create a generic array of HashSet<String>`

Comment: I guess I was too wordy with the question. This should help though. Thanks.

Comment: @BenCole Ah.  It is apparently suggested to either use `HashSet[]` (without generics), **or** `List<HashSet<String>>` (using `List` instead of an array).  Learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you'd need an array of hashsets. Here's what I invision:

```
Set<String> dictionary = new HashSet<String>();

dictionary.add("One");
dictionary.add("Two");
dictionary.add("Three");
dictionary.add("Four");
```

And here is how I would use it. Note: don't read below unless you want an actual answer to the breaking-into-words problem. It may diminish how much learning you get. So only read it if you're okay with it being spoiled.

```
List<String> split(String sentence) {
    List<String> words = new LinkedList<String>();
    String word = ""; // StringBuilder actually is not orders faster in 
                      // this case or I would advocate using it...
    for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        word += sentence.charAt(i); // creates a new String anyway, so StringBuilder
                                    // is far less powerful
        if(dictionary.contains(word) {
            words.add(word);
            word = "";
        }
    }
    return words;
}
```

Some concerns:

Let us assume your sentences and words are all in lowercase, to avoid case sensitivity.
Let us also assume your dictionary contains every common English word.

```
dictionary.add("this");
dictionary.add("is");
dictionary.add("a");
dictionary.add("test");
```

And run "thisisatest" and it will split it properly.

Now, keep in mind there are other words.

```
dictionary.add("i");
dictionary.add("sat");
dictionary.add("est");
```

These are all valid words. Running it will give you

```
"this" "i" "sat" "est"
```

In fact, by this logic, EVERY word that starts with `i` or `a` will end up getting missed. And that's bad. Especially for words like `"apple"` You will get `a` as the first word, then continue searching for `"pple"` and words that start with `"pple"`. That's going to cause a lot of problems!

Even if you can get around this problem, you're going to run into problems where the words are always valid.

Consider "thetreescare". Is it "the" "tree" "scare" or "the" "trees" "care". You are unable to make the differentiation - ever!

So the problem you have picked is a dousie, for sure!

Comment: But would StringBuilder() not produce less references? "word +=" creates a new String object.

Comment: @user968951 The problem is that you would need to create that String object anyway in order to check the map. Although, now that I look at it, you have to create StringBuilder objects for the +=... so it is faster in that sense. But it's not orders faster which StringBuilder intends. Also, if I specifically use a StringBuilder, I will miss out on optimizations in future versions of the JDK. (Consider people who had StringBuffer and had to change it to StringBuilder...)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. For this I guess I would have to go through the whole /usr/share/dict/words and call dictionary.add on each one, then iterate split every time it finds a word. Seems like it would work.

Comment: I will further elaborate on this with an edit since it has some issues that are greater than fit in this comment.

Comment: By the way, the reason I abandoned the length aspect is that if you put them all into one set, you get the same result as if they were in different sets. You'll never have two different length strings be equal anyway, so they'll exist in separate subsets independent of eachother. You wouldn't gain any benefit from separating them unless you were specifically looking for a string of a certain length, where this is the other wya around.

Comment: Re the length, I was thinking that since the length of a string is stored (and thus wouldn't need to be computed every time), that it would make the lookup quicker because it would only need to look through a subset of words. Maybe that's a premature micro-optimization or not even a good idea. I don't know.

Comment: Well I can see how that might be useful. The issue is that using a HashSet it doesn't care about length - it's going to filter by hashCode first, then by equals comparison. So it never compares their length until it does an actual equals.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like:

```
HashSet[] dictionary = new HashSet[20];
// Initialize all sets.
for (int i=0; i<dictionary.length; i++) 
{
    dictionary[i] = new HashSet<String>();
}

for (String word: words) // words is array or list with all possible words
{
    dictionary[word.length()].add(word);
}
```

Comment: Looks like just what I was asking for. Thanks!

Comment: I did not know about compilation problem when using the generic parameter so removed it from the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
HashSet<String>[] mySets = new HashSet[20];
```